# RDS DNS lookup error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how to turn off DNS lookup on an AWS RDS server, MySQL? Keep getting the same error, and its giving me 504 errors.

2014-07-31 12:39:44 14174 [Warning] IP address '222.127.85.158' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it off in your my.cnf file.

See this post: https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/05/31/dns-achilles-heel-mysql-installation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. It's better to use hostnames in the long run anyways. Can't think of many reasons why you'd only want to use IP.

Answer (score 0):

While you should be able to access your RDS instance via its IP, you shouldn't do it.

- Amazon does not guarantee that the IP will always be the same.
- Amazon's failover (multi AZ) switches the IP address behind the DNS entry. So can't use the IP address with a failover setup